# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Calling View methods on another thread than the UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading, illegalstateexception, android-4.4-kitkat, webviewchromium

When trying to open a webview on my nexus 4 now with Android 4.4 (Kit kat) I'll getting this error message:

```
Calling View methods on another thread than the UI thread.; 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Calling View methods on another thread than the UI thread.
com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.createThreadException(WebViewChromium.java:268)
```

Since i update to Android 4.4 my Nexus 4.

Comment: Could you please clarify?  How exactly are you opening the web view?  What do you mean by "Since I update to Android 4.4"?  Do you have any code to show?

Comment: the exception means you should run your code in UI thread. you can use handler or runOnUiThread to fix this issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just check migrating web view of 4.4 google added and changed some things in it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html)

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Code for WebView goes here
    }
});


// This code is BAD and will block the UI thread
webView.loadUrl("javascript:fn()");
while(result == null) {
  Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

what's your code like? you can try

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            // TODO Your code
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

If runOnUiThread is not available for whatever reason, you can also use the following code to bypass this error (say you are wanting access to a View without needing to display it):

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
try
{
    handler.post(
        new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                DesiredMethod(); // Where this method runs the code you're needing
            }
        }
    );
} catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```